# Is it necessary to access an SQLiteDatabase in an AsyncTask?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-sqlite

Is it necessary or even good practice to always access an SQLiteDatabase from an AsyncTask?

Doing it from the UI thread seems to cause no problems and is much simpler to implement.

Comment: Users will tend to consider a frozen UI to be a problem.

Comment: Right, but so far it didn't seem to freeze the UI.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is recommended to not perform IO from your main application thread, but, it does **not** have to be done using an `AsyncTask`.

You have other options for getting out of your main thread too, some of which include the [Loader Framework](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html), [IntentService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html), and [Executors](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html).

Answer (score 4):

It's good practice. Database operations aren't always quick, so Android recommends doing all database and network operations on a background thread (AsyncTask, Runnable, etc).

Answer (score 3):

No, it is not necessary to ALWAYS access your database in another thread. It depends on how long it takes. Usually reads / writes are fast, do not slow down the UI, and do not require another thread. However, when performing lengthy operations like cleanups etc. then yes, it is a good idea to do them in another thread.